# MySQL, glue table counts

Tags: mysql

In a glue table, product_options, I have the following fields... id, productid, optionid

```
CREATE TABLE `product_options` (
`id`  int NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`productid`  int NULL ,
`optionid`  int NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
;

INSERT INTO product_options 
(productid, optionid)
VALUES 
(1,2),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(2,4),(2,3),(2,1),(2,7),(3,1),(3,4),(4,1),(4,7),(4,6),(5,1)
```

(see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d309)

Now, I want to get a count of the products for different combinations of options.

For example, the results I'm after are...
Number of Products with both option id 6 and 7 = 2
Number of Products with all option ids 6, 7 & 1 = 1
Number of Products with option id 1 = 4

I'm having a brain freeze and cannot figure it out - please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select productid from product_options
where optionid in (6,7)
group by productid 
having count(distinct optionid)=2
```

Comment: Sorry - not quite. I've tweaked the question results slightly to show what I'm after. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: OK - so this is actually very close... I just needed to change the code to alter the having count and to make it a derived table with a count:

Comment: Yes based on number optionid the number 2 in having should change

Comment: Thanks Madhivanan - the more I know, the more I know I don't know!

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
select count(*) as count0,opt from
(select productid,group_concat(optionid)as opt from product_options
where optionid in (1)
group by productid 
having count(distinct optionid)=1) a    
UNION    
select count(*) as count0,opt from
(select productid,group_concat(optionid)as opt from product_options
where optionid in (6,7)
group by productid 
having count(distinct optionid)=2) b    
UNION    
select count(*) as count0,opt from
(select productid,group_concat(optionid)as opt from product_options
where optionid in (1,6,7)
group by productid 
having count(distinct optionid)=3) c
```

[SQL DEMO here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d309/49)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_options 
WHERE optionid IN (6, 7) 
GROUP BY productid
```

or if you just want the `COUNT` try

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(productid)) 
FROM product_options 
WHERE optionid IN (6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select productid  from product_options
where optionid in(6,7)
group  by productid 
having COUNT(*)=2
```

Comment: You need distinct count. See my first answer

Comment: @Madhivanan: Amusing there are no duplicate productid, optionid combination.. thanks for your comment